# Which loop is perferred to be used in persistent connection?

Tags: sockets

Which loop should I use to have a single/persistent connection?

In the loop, should I use `send() > 0`, or should I use `while(1)`?

```
while (send() > 0)
{
    because until the message is sent, it should be alive. so should we use send() > 0. 
}
```

or

```
while (1)
{
    infinite loop
}
```

Comment: There's a bit more to it than that.  Can you please explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `send()` returning `> 0` DOES NOT indicate the connection is alive, only that the kernel has not detected an error yet, and has not run out of buffer space for outgoing data. Also, `send()` > 0 doesn't even indicate that the entire message was sent in full.  You need to compare the return value to the number of bytes you ask to send, and if fewer bytes were sent then call `send()` again to finish the job.

Comment: You need to read incoming data to know if the connection is truly alive. If the connection is *closed gracefully*, `recv()` returns 0. If the connection is *lost*, neither `send()` nor `recv()` will return an error until the kernel sees a network error, or an internal timeout elapses - which can be a VERY long time by default (minutes to hours, depending on platform), unless you use `setsockopt(SO_KEEPALIVE)` w/ `TCP_KEEPCNT`, `TCP_KEEPIDLE`, and `TCP_KEEPINTVL`.  Or `WsaIoCtrl(SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS)` on Windows. Or some other platform-specific timeout option.  Or roll your own timeout logic

Comment: Everything that everyone has said above is valid and important, but to answer the question, I prefer an infinite loop in these types of situations.  I have no good reasoning, off the top of my head, to back that up, it's just what I do.